# Does a side wind affect air resistance?

Tags: flow, drag, aerodynamics

I'm trying to figure out whether side wind affects an object's air resistance. I understand that a headwind results in more air resistance, and a tailwind on an object results in less resistance.

My question is, consider this bike moving forward at a rate of 10mph/km, whichever you choose. There is 5mph/km wind coming in from the northwest. Does this count as a headwind? If so, **how do you calculate how side wind affects air resistance**?

I'm using this information for a power meter. [Power meter calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/sports/cycling-wattage#bonus-estimate-your-calories-burnt-from-your-power) So I understand that the factors included are gravity, rolling resistance, aerodynamic drag, speed, and loss. But in this example, I'm only interested if air resistance/headwind(not sure of the proper term) is affected.

[image]

Comment: Look up trigonometry and vectors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @DKNguyen That helped a lot thank you. [Using Trigonometry to Find Vector Components and for Vector Addition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aVShpNbeOA)